# Why cronjob execute multiple time

Tags: python-2.7, cron

My cronjob execute multiple time.
Is my setting wrong??
Please help me

this is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/obe/env/bin/activate
cd /home/obe/env/crawl/pjt/pjt
scrapy crawl gets
```

this is the crontab I set,I use centos7

```
* 23 *  *  * /home/obe/env/crawl/cron_set.sh
```

And I use `ps aux | grep cron`
I found my cronjob execute many time

```
root      1202  0.0  0.0 126336   288 ?        Ss   17:16   0:02 /usr/sbin/crond -n
root      9870  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:00   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root      9908  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:01   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10203  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:09   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10238  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:10   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10269  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:11   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10328  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:13   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10370  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:14   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10412  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:15   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10455  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:16   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10594  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:17   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10631  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:18   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10660  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:19   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10699  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:20   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10731  0.0  0.0 113116     8 ?        Ss   23:21   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10753  0.0  0.0 113116     4 ?        Ss   23:22   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root     10779  0.0  0.0 113116    36 ?        Ss   23:23   0:00 /bin/bash /home/obe/env/clawer/cron_set.sh
root  10802  0.5  0.0 112644   216 pts/2    S+   23:23   0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

Why would this happen???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your crontab *** 23 * * * /home/obe/env/crawl/cron_set.sh** means :

**The command /home/obe/env/crawl/cron_set.sh will execute every minute of 11pm every day.**

If you want it to run once in a day , it should be : **0 23 * * * /home/obe/env/crawl/cron_set.sh** which means

***The command /home/obe/env/crawl/cron_set.sh will execute at 11:00pm every day.***

Next time refer to : http://www.cronchecker.net/

Happy crons

Comment: thanks.But few times,the process really execute just one time,do yo know why??

Comment: Your process has executed every minute of 11 pm not once.

Comment: Oh sorry , I mixed up . ignore what I said.you are right.